# Button Click Twice

Tags: swift, button

As we all know, to avoid clicking twice, we can set the code bellow on the tap method and add a HUD such as SVProgress.show().

```
isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

After the network request, set it to true and SVProgress.dismiss().
I wonder if there is a method to extract the function for those button which needs to send a request. I have thought to use method swizzling. Add this to the button extension, the codes is bellow. It seems not good. Do you guys have some good ways to extract the function? Using inheritance, protocol or something else?

```
extension UIButton {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var cp_submitComplete = "cp_submitComplete"
        static var cp_defaultMessage:String = NSLocalizedString("Loading", comment: "prompt")
        static var cp_customMessage = "cp_customMessage"
    }

    var submitNotComplete: Bool {
        get {
            let objc_Get = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.cp_submitComplete)
            if objc_Get != nil {
                if let objc_Get = objc_Get as? Bool, objc_Get == true {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.cp_submitComplete, newValue as Bool, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            if !newValue {
                isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    var customMessage: String {
        get {
            let cp_customMessage = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.cp_customMessage)
            if let message = cp_customMessage {
                return message as! String
            } else {
                return AssociatedKeys.cp_defaultMessage
            }
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.cp_customMessage, newValue as String, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    override open class func initialize() {
        if self == UIButton.self {
            DispatchQueue.once(NSUUID().uuidString, block: {
                let systemSel = #selector(UIButton.sendAction(_:to:for:))
                let swizzSel = #selector(UIButton.cpSendAction(_:to:for:))

                let systemMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, systemSel)
                let swizzMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzSel)

                let isAdd = class_addMethod(self, systemSel, method_getImplementation(swizzMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzMethod))

                if isAdd {
                    class_replaceMethod(self, swizzSel, method_getImplementation(systemMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(systemMethod));
                } else {
                    method_exchangeImplementations(systemMethod, swizzMethod);
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private dynamic func cpSendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {

        cpSendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        if submitNotComplete {
            //begin submit
            isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: customMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to handle this kind of logic in UIButton. I would rather make the view controller responsible for enabling/disabling the button.

```
func handleTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: customMessage)
    doSomeTaskAsync(withCompletion: {
        sender.isEnabled = true
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    })
}
```

Comment: do you mean that extracting the function for those buttons is not good or my way to implement it is not good?

Comment: I mean that your approach seems to be overcomplicated. You also embed SVProgressHUD in extensions of UIButton. In my opinion this is a wrong architectural solution